# Where does half of the work done in charging a capacitor is dissipated?

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, voltage, capacitance, dissipation

The energy stored in a charged capacitor of capacitance $C$ with $V$ voltage across it is:

$$U= \frac 12 CV^2$$

Whereas the work done in charging the capacitor is:

$$W= CV^2$$

This means that $(1/2)CV^2$ amount of energy gets dissipated somewhere else.

I learnt somewhere that this is dissipated as heat. But an ideal circuit having just a capacitor with a battery (without internal resistance) provides no resistance.

So:

- How and where does half of the work done in charging a capacitor gets dissipated?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187774/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you for citing that duplicate. The answer there was quite helpful and answers both of my question (i.e., how and why)!

Comment: The only correct answer in the cited "duplicate" is that of @my2cts

Comment: The second equation in this question is incorrect...  There is no missing energy to explain.