# I am confused on how to think about potential energy stored in capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, voltage, capacitance

Energy stored in capacitors is represented by
$$U = \frac{1}{2} QV$$

Now I have heard 2 reasons why there’s a half factor, unlike the general potential energy equation, which is $U = QV$.

1. Capacitors should’ve stored $QV$ amounts of energy. But, because electrons are being pushed to a negative plate, and electrons are being pulled off from an increasing positive plate, work is being done and half of $QV$ is needed to do work. The remaining half is the energy stored in capacitors.
2. When you are discharging a capacitor, voltage keeps on decreasing as charge keeps on decreasing. As a result, energy keeps on decreasing and the sum of the energy transferred happens to be half of $QV$.

I don’t really know what’s the correct way to approach this. Both sound equally valid to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a $1/2$ appear in this simple capacitor equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112404/)

Comment: Also see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644542/i-am-confused-on-how-to-think-about-potential-energy-stored-in-capacitors), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/610013/when-we-charge-a-capacitor-via-a-battery-then-why-does-exactly-1-2-of-the-work#comment1373362_610013), [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337516/is-the-50-loss-of-energy-when-charging-a-cap-from-a-battery-a-set-rule-in-stone),

Comment: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337487/a-capacitor-stores-half-the-energy-when-charged-from-a-battery-each-and-every-ti), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187774/what-happens-to-half-of-the-energy-in-a-circuit-with-a-capacitor), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109845/energy-conservation-when-capacitor-charges-in-a-zero-resistance-circuit), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232267/saving-energy-while-charging-capacitor).

Answer (score 1):

Reason 1: It takes work to keep pushing electrons onto the capacitor plate, to overcome the electric repulsion. Half the energy is lost to this.